# Apache Connect Exception during heavy indexing on ElasticSearch

Tags: spring, elasticsearch

I am facing a java.net.ConnectException when I performing indexing on ElasticSearch using a Java high level Rest Client.
This is the stack trace

```
java.net.ConnectException
    at org.apache.http.nio.pool.RouteSpecificPool.timeout(RouteSpecificPool.java:168)
    at org.apache.http.nio.pool.AbstractNIOConnPool.requestTimeout(AbstractNIOConnPool.java:561)
    at org.apache.http.nio.pool.AbstractNIOConnPool$InternalSessionRequestCallback.timeout(AbstractNIOConnPool.java:822)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.SessionRequestImpl.timeout(SessionRequestImpl.java:183)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.DefaultConnectingIOReactor.processTimeouts(DefaultConnectingIOReactor.java:210)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.DefaultConnectingIOReactor.processEvents(DefaultConnectingIOReactor.java:155)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.execute(AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.java:348)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.conn.PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager.execute(PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager.java:192)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.CloseableHttpAsyncClientBase$1.run(CloseableHttpAsyncClientBase.java:64)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Increase your request time out or reduce/chunk your data size

Comment: Tried increasing the request timeout.Not working.Also simply increasing the value does not seem like a scalable solution.Data size is 1 only.Many requests are being invoked.

Comment: I meant the client side backoff time for the request but can't be sure without looking at the code. If the data size is 1 why are you sending in multiple async calls?

Comment: Yeah tried increasing the timeout using the setConnectionTimeout method to no avail.I am getting frequent single document inserts.For inserting 1 document,I am making 1 call to ES.